# Thunar lost files after dragging to and dropping onto folder!

Tags: xubuntu, files, thunar

I made some new folders, and then dragged files to them, to organize them in Thunar.  I then opened the folders, and the files are not there!

I opened the folder properties, and it says there are items, and shows me their combined size, but I can not see the files!!!!

Show hidden files is on, and the files were not hidden to begin with. The drive they are on is NTFS.

Ubuntu Studio 15.04, am a Linux newbe.

Comment: Try hitting `F5` to refresh the folder view.

Comment: Refreshing, and reloading did not change it, but just now I closed Thunar altogether, and opened it up again, viola' the files are now showing.

This is obviously a bug, where should I report it?

Comment: Sometimes it just doesn't update the folder view. I thought `F5` would help, but I've never used Thunar. Glad that you got it resolved though.

Comment: I feel I need to add that this behavior seem to exist in 2022 (Thunar 4.16.11). If I open an archive in a archive manager, update it by adding a file to it, the archive disappears from the file view in Thunar. However it does reappear after a refresh (F5 or Ctrl+r).
Additionally however, if not doing a refresh I have experienced that Thunar crash with some operations.

Comment: https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/bugs will provide you with information on open bugs & how to report to Xfce. Or you can go directly to the Thunar repo: https://gitlab.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/-/issues?scope=all&state=all

Answer (score 0):

After closing Thunar, and then reopening it the files now show as they are supposed to.  Now it would be great if someone could figure out why this is happening, and post a permanent fix, and it's developers fix the offending software, as it is really scary when files go missing!!!!!!!!